# How to have collectionViewCell start from center of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, storyboard, constraints

Show collection view with 3 columns & 2 rows at centre of the screen with respective to any mobile device size. Which also holds a header to it of size card 184 height.

When running application on iPhone5 or iPhoneSE its shows three rows and two columns.

How to center the collectionViewCells with three columns and two rows with respective any device size?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For your collection view choose vertically in container and then change constraint to First item: collectionView top, Second item: superview center Y. Then set collectionView bottom to superview bottom. and do your cells resizable